# Background Image is flickering on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover, mouseenter

I was trying to change my background image on a mouseover, the images are changing but the transition is flickering and the fadeIN/Out seems not working …

Code:

css:

```
.background {
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/angst.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

js:

```
$( ".project_link_01" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $('.background').css('backgroundImage','url(../img/test.png)').fadeIn();
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $('.background').css('backgroundImage','url(../img/angst.png)');
});
```

Comment: The flickering might be happening because of lag in loading the images as you are pulling them up when the mouseover has already happened. Try preloading them.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `css` `:hover`

```css
.background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: background 500ms;
}
.background:hover {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics" style="display:none;" />
<div class="background"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to preload the images like in:

```
<img src="test.png" style="display:none">
```

For each of it.

Or use a sprite:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites.

Comment: And you might try throttling or debouncing the event stream.  underscore.js, among others, has some convenient methods that can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But its still flickering. 
Its a fullscreen background and the background should change on every link hover with a different image.

Comment: Is it really flickering after preloading it? Hmm, could you make a http://jsfiddle.net?